# How to know when moving row is done

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My app allows user to reorder rows in a table view, but I want to `reloadData` after moving is done to change something (add some text to the first row).

I tried to `reloadData` in `moveRowAtIndexPath:` method, but it makes the app hang because this method is called many time (according number of rows need to be moved) and the table view is reload many time.

So, I just want to know when the moving behavior is done then I `reloadData` in just one time. Does anyone know about this? Please help me. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)doReload
{
  [myTable reloadData];
}
```

You can do `[self performSelector:selector(doReload) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1]` in the `moveRowAtIndexPath` method but you can't call `[myTable reloadData]` directly because as you found it causes a loop. Basically you need to allow the table manipulation to finish and the run loop to get around to calling your method which then causes a reload of your table. This is a bit of a hack but it works well. Ordinarily you don't need `reloadData` at this point but you may be trying to do something out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(int)table:(UITable*)table movedRow: (int)row toRow: (int)dest
```

Comment: It's seem this overload method is make sense, but It is not run